# Order by clause is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out the average price for each model in the top 5 manufacturers, in terms of sales quantity, and order by average price.

I had tried the below code but getting error -

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 602
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Can anyone please help me to correct it?

```
SELECT TOP 5
    Manufacturer_Name AS [Manufacturer],
    AVG(TotalPrice) AS [average total price],
    SUM(Quantity) AS [sales quantity]
FROM 
    FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1 
LEFT JOIN 
    DIM_MODEL M1 ON T1.IDModel = M1.IDModel 
INNER JOIN 
    DIM_MANUFACTURER M2 ON M1.IDManufacturer = M2.IDManufacturer
WHERE
    T1.IDModel IN (SELECT T1.IDModel FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1
                   GROUP BY T1.IDModel
                   ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC)
GROUP BY 
    Manufacturer_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You had `ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC` within a subquery, thus causing the error. `ORDER BY` will have no effect in the subquery as it only really changes the order of the results displayed at the end, thus the error (unless you use it in conjunction with TOP ..., which it then serves a different purpose and is allowed).

Here's what it should be:

```
SELECT TOP 5
Manufacturer_Name as [Manufacturer],
AVG(TotalPrice) as [average total price],
sum(Quantity) as [sales quantity]
FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1 LEFT JOIN DIM_MODEL M1
ON T1.IDModel=M1.IDModel INNER JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER M2 ON M1.IDManufacturer=M2.IDManufacturer
where T1.IDModel in (select T1.IDModel from FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1
group by T1.IDModel)
GROUP BY Manufacturer_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving is saying precisely what's wrong with your query. You cannot use the `ORDER BY` clause within a subquery, unless `TOP`,`OFFSET` or `FOR XML` is also specified. So basically

```sql
WHERE
    T1.IDModel IN (SELECT T1.IDModel FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1
                   GROUP BY T1.IDModel
                   ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC)
```

is incorrect, while

```sql
WHERE
    T1.IDModel IN (SELECT TOP 1 T1.IDModel FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1
                   GROUP BY T1.IDModel
                   ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC)
```

should work fine.

Furthermore, your `GROUP BY` clause has no effect. If the point of that subquery is to check wether or not you have a record of the current `T1.IDModel` in the `FACT_TRANSACTIONS` table, I suggest using

```sql
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS FT WHERE FT.IDModel = T1.IDModel
)
```

This should make your query run faster.

Answer (score 0):

in this section

```
    T1.IDModel IN (SELECT T1.IDModel FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1
               GROUP BY T1.IDModel
               ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC)
```

you don't need to use order by, the result will be passed to the `T1.IDModel IN` anyway. so  the order by section is surplus.

Answer (score 0):

You are already joining on the keys used in the `IN`.  So, just change the outer join to an inner join and remove that condition entirely.

I am going to speculate that you want the result set of the entire query ordered:

```
SELECT Manufacturer_Name AS [Manufacturer],
       AVG(TotalPrice) AS [average total price],
       SUM(Quantity) AS [sales quantity]
FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1 JOIN 
     DIM_MODEL M1
     ON T1.IDModel = M1.IDModel INNER JOIN 
     DIM_MANUFACTURER M2
     ON M1.IDManufacturer = M2.IDManufacturer
GROUP BY Manufacturer_Name
ORDER BY AVG(T1.TotalPrice) DESC;
```

Note that the error is quite clear.  You cannot specify an `ORDER BY` in a subquery, unless the subquery has `SELECT TOP` or `OFFSET`/`FETCH`.  This is actually explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The SELECT query of a subquery is always enclosed in parentheses. It cannot include a COMPUTE or FOR BROWSE clause, and may only include an ORDER BY clause when a TOP clause is also specified.

Note:  I don't know why this version of the documentation leaves out `OFFSET`/`FETCH` as an exception.